# pointer to interface is not an interface error?

Tags: pointers, inheritance, go

The following code works:

```
type Brace interface {}

type Round struct {
    prev_ Brace
}

type Square struct {}

func main() {
    var r Round
    var s Square
    r.prev_ = s
}
```

Is it true that `r.prev_` is now a copy of `s`? How can I change it that Round will contain a pointer to Brace? This code doesn't work:

```
type Brace interface {}

type Round struct {
    prev_ *Brace
}

type Square struct {}

func main() {
    var r Round
    var s Square
    r.prev_ = &s
}
```

because of the error:

> cannot use &s (type *Square) as type *Brace in assignment:
>   *Brace is pointer to interface, not interface

Comment: Forget about trying traditional, inheritance based OOP in Go: It **does** **not** **work**, no matter how hard you try. Really. Redesign. Doing (or even mimicking) traditional OOP in Go will just lead to bugs, problems and pain. You gain _nothing_ by doing it this way.

Comment: As @Volker says Golang not works like object oriented technology. There is a difference on how interface works in go.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but can you show how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the error says:

> cannot use &s (type *Square) as type *Brace in assignment: *Brace is
>   pointer to interface, not interface

An interface can wrap any type of value. But you are wraping the struct inside pointer type interface not an interface. That's not how interface works in golang.

If you wants to pass the address of an struct. An interface can wrap the pointer to struct directly. There is no need of creating a pointer to an interface to achieve that.

```
type Brace interface {}

type Round struct {
    prev_ Brace
}

type Square struct {}

func main() {
    var r Round
    var s Square
    r.prev_ = &s
    fmt.Printf("%#v", r)
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/F1fzWT1_GcT)

In Golang you should avoid passing a pointer to interface as:

> The compiler will complain about this error but the situation can
>   still be confusing, because sometimes a pointer is necessary to
>   satisfy an interface. The insight is that although a pointer to a
>   concrete type can satisfy an interface, with one exception a pointer
>   to an interface can never satisfy an interface.

Consider the variable declaration,

```
var w io.Writer
```

The printing function fmt.Fprintf takes as its first argument a value that satisfies io.Writer—something that implements the canonical Write method. Thus we can write

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, world\n")
```

If however we pass the address of w, the program will not compile.

```
fmt.Fprintf(&w, "hello, world\n") // Compile-time error.
```

> The one exception is that any value, even a pointer to an interface,
>   can be assigned to a variable of empty interface type (interface{}).
>   Even so, it's almost certainly a mistake if the value is a pointer to
>   an interface; the result can be confusing.

Check it on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DtUzToDV0pq). You will find the same error you are getting in your code snippet when trying to pass pointer to interface.

Comment: Thank you! But this way `Type(r.prev_) == Brace`, not `Square`. In my first block of code am I right that `r.prev_` is now a copy of `s`?

Comment: @InFamousX yes In go lang every thing is passed by value. So you are passing the copy of struct not struct itself.

Comment: @InFamousX To compare the underlying values of interface you should use type assertion